# Unexpected leading underscore with babel's playground

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

Take a look at the following class "data" method. The method body contains
a variable called "result", and is reassigned in the else if clause to an array.

For some reason babel transpiles the aforementioned variable with a leading underscore.

ES6 class:

```
class Serie {
  constructor( name, data = [] ) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false,
      writable: false,
      value: name
    })

    data.map( (v, i) => this[v.name] = v.value );
  }

  data( name ) {
    let result = null;

    if ( arguments.length == 1 ) {
      result = this.hasOwnProperty( name ) ? this[ name ] : result;
    }
    else if ( arguments.length == 0 ) {
      let keys   = Object.keys(this),
          i      = keys.length,
          result = [];

      while ( i-- ) {
        result.push( this[ keys[i] ] );
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  // ...
}
```

The transpiled method:

```
function data(name) {
      var result = null;

      if (arguments.length == 1) {
        result = this.hasOwnProperty(name) ? this[name] : result;
      } else if (arguments.length == 0) {
        var keys = Object.keys(this),
            i = keys.length,
            _result = [];

        while (i--) {
          _result.push(this[keys[i]]);
        }
      }

      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is being re-*declared*, not just reassigned, using `let`, so scoped to the current block (the *else if* block).

When transpiled to `var`, which doesn't adhere to block scoping, the second declaration should not overwrite the first one.

It's basically the difference between this:

```
let a = 123;
if (true) {
  let a = 456;
}
// a === 123
```

And this:

```
var a = 123;
if (true) {
  var a = 456;
}
// a === 456
```

Comment: Oh crap ! I totally missed that. Thank you.